# Protractor - Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0

Tags: javascript, protractor

I wonder if anyone has managed to solve this issue? Basically I use this function

```
this.removeContributorFromPermissions = function(name) {
        $('button[title="Unlock owner management options"]').click();
        browser.sleep(2000); // here to create a delay until button appears.
        var remove = element.all(by.repeater('existingOwner in companyOwners')).filter(function(rowElement){
            return rowElement.element(by.css('td[ng-bind="existingOwner.Name"]')).getText().then(function(text){
                return text.trim() == name;
            });
        });
        remove.first().$('.btn.close').click();
        element(by.buttonText('Remove')).click();
    };
```

And these two asserts

```
it('Newly added new contributor is deleted from the company permissions', function() {
        settingsPage.removeContributorFromPermissions(browser.params.settings.contributors.newContributorName);
        var owners = element.all(by.repeater('existingOwner in companyOwners').column('existingOwner.Name'));
        expect(owners).not.toContain(browser.params.settings.contributors.newContributorName);
    });

it('Newly added existing contributor is deleted from the company permissions', function() {
        settingsPage.removeContributorFromPermissions(browser.params.settings.contributors.existingContributorName);
        var owners = element.all(by.repeater('existingOwner in companyOwners').column('existingOwner.Name'));
        expect(owners).not.toContain(browser.params.settings.contributors.existingContributorName);
    });
```

The first iteration runs through and successfully deletes the user, but the second one stops after completing the browser.sleep();

Full Error

```
1) Testing company permission area Newly added existing contributor is deleted from the company permissions
  - Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator by.repeater("existingOwner in companyOwners")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your 2s hard sleep is not enough and thats what is making tests flaky (during 1st iteration its enough but during seconds its not). Have you considered using [ExpectedConditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

```
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var repeaterElement = element(by.repeater('existingOwner in companyOwners'));

    //Wait up to 10 seconds for elements to be visible
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(repeaterElement), 10000);
    var remove = element.all(by.repeater('existingOwner in companyOwners')).filter(function(rowElement){
            return rowElement.element(by.css('td[ng-bind="existingOwner.Name"]')).getText().then(function(text){
                 return text.trim() == name;
            });
    });
    remove.first().$('.btn.close').click();
    element(by.buttonText('Remove')).click();
```

Comment: Cheers Nilesh I'll give it try and let you know.

Comment: Still the same error. Its a hassle I'll tell you that much